# How to store string values in string array?

Tags: java, string

I wanted to store name values in `String a[] = new String[3];`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bo = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String name = bo.readLine();
        String a[] = new String[3];
    }
}
```

Comment: `a[index] = name;` you can do it with `for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){a[i] = name}` or you can use some variable like `counter = 0;` and `a[counter] = name; counter++;`

Answer (score 5):

I guess this should suffice:

```
String a[] = new String[3];

for(int i=0; i<a.length;i++) {
    String name = bo.readLine();
    a[i] = name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `name` represents names separated by space, try this:

```
String a[] = name.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working from the console I think this is the easiest way for a beginner to tackle user input:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadToStringArray {

    private static String[] stringArray  = new String[3];

    // method that reads user input into the String array
    private static void readToArray() {

        Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);

        // read from the console 3 times
        for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a string to put at position " + i + " of the array: ");
            stringArray[i] = scanIn.nextLine();
        }
        scanIn.close();
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readToArray();

        // print out the stringArray contents
        for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("String at position " + i + " of the array: " + stringArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

This method uses the java's native Scanner class. You can just copy and paste this and it will work.